# How to use to different columns to run a function

Tags: r, function

I am just starting to use R and there is a lot I don't know. I have a function to find irradiance in a data set based on start and end date. I made two dataframes one for the starting dates and one for the end. But when I input the name for each dataframe for the beginning and end date I get this error

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

`getlightData` is the function I created.
It works when I manually input the begin and end dates but now I want it to run based on the list of begin and end dates I created.
This is the line of code I run

```
getlightData(beginDates[1:25], endDates[1:25], product="high_low")
```

I was expecting to get an output of irradiance values based on each start and end date

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message occurs when you try to insert multiple file names in a function (e.g. read.csv2()). Maybe it would be helpful to see the whole function. When functions take vectors as input, you might have to specify elements of the vectors in the function instead of using the whole vector.

Comment: This answer should be a comment on the parent post.

Comment: Sorry I do not have enough reputation.